# Which functor does the projective space represent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I hope this question isn't too silly. It is certainly fundamental, so the answer is likely contained at least implicitly in most sources out there, but I haven't seen it done this way (that is, in this particular functorial manner) in a way which is overt enough for me to catch on. I am familiar with the classical $Proj$-construction for a graded ring, so that's not quite what I'm looking for.

Let $k$ be a ring. Let's call a covariant functor of sets on some category of $k$-algebras an algebraic functor (over $k$). The affine $I$-space over $k$ is the algebraic functor $\mathbb{A}^I:(k−alg)→(set)$ which takes a $k$-algebra $R$ to the set $\mathbb{R}^I$ of $I$-tuples of elements of $R$. This functor is (co)representable by the ring $k[T_i],i∈I$, so $\mathbb{A}^I$ is (represented by) an affine scheme.

I want the projective space over $k$ in terms of an algebraic functor over $k$. I'm thinking something like $R↦\{\mathbb{R}^{I+∞}/\mathbb{G}_m(R)\}$ (where $\mathbb{G}_m(R)$ is the multiplicative group of $R$), or as a functor sending $R$ to some set of modules of rank $1$. One should then be able to show that it has a cover by four copies of the affine $I$-space over $k$. Alternatively, it would likely make sense to consider it a functor on the category of graded $k$-algebras.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Classically, if $K$ is a field, then $\mathbb P^n(K)$ is the set of lines $L\subset K^{n+1}$ of the vector space $K^{n+1}$.

If $R$ is a ring, the correct generalization of  a line in $R^{n+1}$ is a projective submodule $L\subset R^{n+1}$ of rank one,  which is also a direct summand : $ R^{n+1}= L\oplus E$, where $E$ is projective of rank $n$.
We call such submodules *supplemented line bundles* and $\mathbb P^n(R)$ is the set of these.

Beware that it is not automatic that a projective submodule of rank one of $ R^{n+1} $ is a direct summand, even if it is free :
 for example the submodule $2\mathbb Z\oplus 0\subset \mathbb Z^2$ is free of  rank one but not a direct summandand and is thus not an element of  $\mathbb P^1(\mathbb Z)$ .
However a free $R$-module $R(r_0,r_1,\cdots ,r_n)\subset R^{n+1}$ *is* a supplemented line bundle iff the $r_i$'s generate $R$ i.e. $\Sigma Rr_i=R$

Because of Grothendieck's vast generalization mentioned by Martin one also considers the dual definition of $\mathbb P^n(R)$ as equivalence classes of projective $R$-modules  of rank one $Q$ equipped with a surjective morphism $R^{n+1}\to Q$.

Comment: Thank you! Another good answer. Hard to know which one to pick, but I think I'll go for this one because it is closer to the generality I asked for. I also found this treated in a set of notes by Strickland on formal schemes.

Comment: Ah, the condition that the $r_i$ generate $R$ got much clearer when considering that this means that they do not all vanish at any point. This plugs nicely into thinking about projective schemes as looking for strictly non-trivial solutions to homogeneous equations. Neat :-)

Comment: @Georges Elencwajg just curious ...so the set {rank 1 free submodules of $V \otimes k [x]/x^2$ } is actually tangent bundle of $\mathbb {P}^1$?

Comment: Minor note: If $L$ is a direct summand of $R^{n+1}$, it is automatically projective, so you can just say rank one direct summands of $R^{n+1}$.

Comment: Also, it might be worth giving an example of a non-free summand. Let $R = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ and let $I$ be the ideal $(2, \sqrt{-5}+1)$ in $R$. Then $R^2 \cong I^2$ by $(x,y) \mapsto ((1+\sqrt{-5}) x + 2 y, 2 x + (1-\sqrt{-5}) y)$.

Comment: @David: sorry, I dont understand your example. What is your $L$ ? Is it a submodule of $R^2$? The notation $I^2$ stands for $I\times I$ , I suppose, rather than the usual square of the ideal $I$?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Yes, $I^2$ is $I \times I$. I should have written $I^{\oplus 2}$, that would probably be clearest. So $I$ is a summand of $I^{\oplus 2} \cong R^{\oplus 2}$.

Comment: Thank you, @David E Speyer.

Comment: I am confused. It seems to me that quotients cannot be canonically identified with direct summands (or supplemented submodules as you call). I don't know whether I am mistaken, but if we take an algebraic vector bundle $E$, then the two definitions are not equivalent (the two are related by duality)?

Answer (score 18):

If $S$ is a scheme and $\mathcal{E}$ is a locally free module on $S$, then the projective space bundle $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E}) \to S$ represents the following functor:

$\mathrm{Sch}/S \to \mathrm{Set}, (f:X \to S) \mapsto \{\text{invertible quotients of } f^* \mathcal{E}\}$

You can find this in every introduction to algebraic geometry, for example EGA I (1970), § 9. Actually this is the *definition* of $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{E})$ and then it can be shown with a general principle (every Zariski sheaf, which is locally representable, is representable) that this functor is representable by a scheme.

In the special case $\mathcal{E} = \mathcal{O}_S^{d+1}$, one writes $\mathbb{P}^d_S$ for this $S$-scheme and it represents the functor

$\mathrm{Sch}/S \to \mathrm{Set}, (f:X \to S) \mapsto \{\text{invertible quotients of } \mathcal{O}_X^{d+1}\}.$

Of course you can even specify to $S=\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ for some ring $k$ and restrict to $k$-algebras. But in my opinion it is hard to really understand the projective space when only defined as a functor on $k$-algebras. By the way, I first understood Grassmannians when I learned the general "global" definition in loc. cit. - these chart definitions in topology are only confusing ...

Comment: Thank you! I agree charts might not be all too great for understanding projective spaces, but the first thing I really understood and liked was the projective line, patched together by pieces of $k[t]$. It makes it clear to me why a meromorphic function on $X$ is the same thing as a morphism $X\to\mathbb{P}^1$. This complements nicely the notion of a regular function as a morphism $X\to\mathbb{A}^1$. If I was able to see from the definition of $\mathbb{P}^I$, that this was the case I would be every happy. At least you've told me what I need to stare at until it makes sense :-)

Comment: Charts can be confusing, but they are useful for doing local calculations.  It's important to understand both approaches (as well as the homogeneous space point of view).

Comment: Michael: I agree, but often computations with charts are made without any global data. This is always confusing and clumsy. @Eivind: You can derive this from the functorial definition.

Comment: This got way clearer with time. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Eivind: I am very glad to hear that.