# Confusion regarding definition of Grassmannian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, grassmannian

I had been thinking of Grass$(p,r)$ as the set of $r$ dim subspaces of $k^p$ where $k$ is whatever ground field we take in the context. We then topologize this set.

Now in one of his papers, Nitsure starts by saying : **Let $G = G(p,r)$ be the Grassmannian variety of $r$-dim quotients of $k^p$**

He also goes on to say that we can think of the same as **$SL(p)/P$ where $P$ is a parabolic subgroup.**

> Why does he call them quotients whereas in differential geometry we think of the elements as subspaces?

> How do we get the second formulation and what is $P$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does he call them quotients whereas in differential geometry we think of the elements as subspaces?

This becomes becomes more evident, when you want to work with the projective space as a scheme instead of a manifold or abstract variety. Let's look at the easiest case, the projective line: When $k$ is a field, there is no difference between quotients and subspaces, since everything is split. When we want to look at $\mathbb{P}^1_k(R)$ for an $R$-algebra $k$ (really you can do this for any $R$-algebra), you might be tempted to define it via subspaces, but this turns out to be insufficient, whereas quotients yield a more easy description. I recommend you look at [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121105/which-functor-does-the-projective-space-represent). As a caveat it should be stressed, that also you have to switch from free modules to projective modules.

> How do we get the second formulation and what is $P$?

$P$ in this case is the $(r,p-r)$ parabolic. There are matrixes where the lower left $(p-r)\times r$ block is just $0$.  The map goes as follows: Let's define $x\in G(p,r)$ to be the standard flag, i.e. $x=<e_1,...,e_r>$ with $e_i$ the standard basis. Given an element $g\in SL(p)$, we set $g.x:=<g(e_1),...,g(e_r)>$. You should verify that this defines a well-defined action. So you get a map
$$ SL(p)\to Gr(r,p)$$
sending $g$ to $g.x$. This is surjective, because the action is transitive. Finally you verify that $Stab_{SL(p)}(x)=P$, so you get exactly that $$ SL(p)/P\to Gr(r,p)$$ is an isomorphism. This isomorphism in fact exists in greater generality for any parabolic subgroups (don't worry if you don't know what that means). You can consult [these notes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410240.pdf) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I'd like to ask a follow-up question. The way you defined the Grassmannian (and in fact I also looked it up just now), we get a universal r rank bundle over it. Nitsure also says that this universal bundle corresponds to a representation of $P$ where $P$ is the parabolic subgroup as you said. Is there a way to say what the representation/correspondence is? Thanks again.

Comment: Could give me a reference for that?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://math.mit.edu/events/talbot/2011/library/nitsure_moduli_of_semistable_pairs.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiuuPD88__2AhXHSmwGHa9FDe8QFnoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw3_9Gbm7pva5Z6I5Q7KEuRn

Comment: I hope this link works.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know the answer off the top of my head